# Escaping a literal <?php and <? in a PHP script

Tags: escaping, php

I am templatizing my php.ini using PHP. I have a script to set up a development environment by generating httpd.conf, apachectl, and php.ini from templates using a CLI PHP script. Unfortunately there are literal `<?` and `<?php` strings in php.ini (in a comment). Is it possible to escape those somehow so php doesn't interpret them as normal PHP escape sequences?

Currently my workaround is to wrap them in a real PHP escape sequence that outputs them as a string, like this:

```
; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
; <?php echo "<? and ?>" ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
; recommended for several years that you not use the short tag "short cut" and
; instead to use the full <?php echo "<?php and ?>" ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use
;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
<?php echo "<?php"; ?>
```

Will output:

```
<?php
```

Comment: Works.  There's seriously no way to actually escape `<?`?

Comment: Nope. No way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the whole ini inside heredoc as follows

```
<?php 
echo <<< EOF
<?php echo "stuff inside php tag"; ?>
EOF;
?>
```

Which when output doesn't render in the page but appears on the page source
or you can use html encoding for the tags

```
&lt;?php echo 'this'; ?&gt;
```

I think the later will suit you better.
If that doesn't do the job you could use ASCII encoding which I don't know much about

Comment: "EOF type thingy which I don't know the name of" -> "Heredoc"

Comment: HTML encoding would only work if the output were HTML. It's not—it's a php.ini file

Comment: @nohat, wouldn't it be possible to store the heredoc value inside a variable and save it to a file, .ini or otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

A quick & simple solution would to search through the php.ini and replace all  within comments with unique markers, after the file has been parsed, simply replace those unique markers back with the corresponding php tag.